# Создание итератора для двумерного массива в джава

Tags: java

пример jagged array - {{1}, {2,3,4,5,},{6,7},{8,9,10,11,12,}} корректно должно обрабатываться не только jagged array а также квадратная матрица. Метод next() должен вернуть последовательность цифр

Answer (score 2):

Вот итератор:

```
import java.util.Iterator;
public class ArrayIterator implements Iterator<Integer> {
  private Integer[][] m;
  private int i, j;
  public ArrayIterator(Integer[][] m) {
    this.m = m;
  }
  @Override
  public boolean hasNext() {
    return i < m.length && j < m[i].length;
  }
  @Override
  public Integer next() {
    Integer r = m[i][j++];
    if (j >= m[i].length) {
      i++;
      j = 0;
    }
    return r;
  }
}
```

Вот его использование:

```
public class Main {
  public static void main(String[] args) {
    Integer[][] array = new Integer[][]{{1}, {2,3,4,5,},{6,7},{8,9,10,11,12,}};
    ArrayIterator i = new ArrayIterator(array);
    for (;i.hasNext();) {
      System.out.println(i.next());
    }
  }
}
```

Я конечно не фанат изобретения велосипедов, ибо можно было через вложенный итератор всё решить, или через стрим, как в ответе выше, но думаю, что задача решается легко и просто двумя счётчиками.

И да, если надо, чтоб итератор работал конкретно с примитивом int, то лучше не реализовывать интерфейс Iterator. И тогда конечно же все Integer можно будет заменить на int

Answer (score 0):

Попробуйте примерно так (пример как с вызовом итератора, так и через стрим):

```
import java.util.Iterator;
import java.util.LinkedList;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.stream.Stream;

public class ArrayIterator <T> implements Iterable <T> {

    private final List<T> elements;

    public ArrayIterator(T[][] array) {
        elements = new LinkedList<>();
        for (T[] array1 : array) {
            for (T array11 : array1) elements.add(array11);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public Iterator<T> iterator() {
        return elements.iterator();
    }

    public Stream<T> stream() {
        return elements.stream();
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        Integer[][]array =  {{1},{2,3,4,5,},{6,7},{8,9,10,11,12,}};        
        ArrayIterator <Integer> arrayIterator = new ArrayIterator<>(array);
        Iterator<Integer> iterator = arrayIterator.iterator();
        while(iterator.hasNext()) System.out.println(iterator.next()); 

        System.out.println("*************************************************");

        arrayIterator.stream().forEach(System.out::println);

    }

}
```